# $error.required is coming out as false on button click

Tags: angularjs

I have set attribute `ng-required="true"` in my dropdownlist.

On button click I want to validate the dropdown. But initially $error.required displays `false` which should be `true`.

However if I change the value of dropdownlist $error.require works perfectly fine.

```
 <select id="ddlsolution" name="ddlsolution" ng-model="Detail.CCESolution" ng-options="solutionName.id as solutionName.type for solutionName in solutionNames" ng-required="true">
                                            <option value="">-- Select Solution --</option>
                                        </select>

<button type="submit" class="gradient-button1" style="float: right; margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 10px;" ng-click="validateFields()">Submit</button>


function validateFields() {
            if ($scope.registrationForm.ddlsolution.$error.required) {
                alert("error");
            }
            else {
                alert("no error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can use 'required' attribute instead of 'ng-required'

Comment: that doesn't work.

Comment: Try ng-required="required"

Comment: can you provide plunker or fiddle

Comment: What you are describing is not how it should behave. Can you reproduce the issue? Because setting ngRequired to true on empty select will make it required: true for sure, unless you messed up something in your code.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("Demo", []);
app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
  $scope.validateFields = function(valid) {
    if (valid) {
      alert("valid")
    } else {
      alert("invalid")
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-form="regForm">
      <select id="ddlsolution" name="ddlsolution" ng-model="selectedDdl" required>
        <option value="">-- Select Solution --</option>
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
      </select>

      <button type="submit" class="gradient-button1" ng-click="validateFields(regForm.$valid)">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/03L3faq5/9/

Hope it will be helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$invalid` like as follows

```js
var app = angular.module("Demo", []);

 app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
   
   $scope.validateFields = function() {
     
   if($scope.myForm.ddlsolution.$invalid){
      alert("error");  
   }else{
    alert("no error");  
   }
     
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-form="myForm">
      <select id="ddlsolution" name="ddlsolution" ng-model="Detail.CCESolution" required>
        <option >-- Select Solution --</option>
        <option value="value1">Value</option>
        <option value="value2">Value</option>
      </select>

      <button type="submit" class="gradient-button1" style="float: right; margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 10px;" ng-click="validateFields()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```